# how to upload and download a photo and video file to dropbox from my app android?

Tags: android

How can I upload a photo and video file with my Android app using the Dropbox API to Dropbox i'd gone through the tutorial on the Dropbox Developers of coreAPI and now i want to create my app for that in Create a new Dropbox Platform app it asks to choose What type of app do you want to create? i'm little bit confused in that if any one have idea about please help me guys.

Answer (score 2):

```
page and could get the sample example.
[DropBox Api SDK example ][1]
[Step by step integration Dropbox Tutorial 2][3]
[Tutorial 1][2]


  [1]: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/android
  [2]: http://javatechig.com/android/share-file-to-dropbox-in-android-example
  [3]: http://www.theappguruz.com/tutorial/10-steps-integrate-dropbox-api-android/
```